# Interface stopped working when Compiz effects are on

Tags: 11.10, compiz, gnome-classic

I've been running Gnome-classic with Compiz effects since the release of 11.10.

Today, I rebooted, and the gnome panel, docky window manager, and basically all interface elements stopped loading when I log in. All I see is my desktop wallpaper, and that's it. So far as I know, I've made no changes, I certainly didn't make any settings changes for my interface. There might have been some kind up update since I last booted, but that's about it.

I can log out by hitting CTRL+ALT+DEL, and then if I log in again to Gnome-classic with no effects, then I have a working system.

I know better than to even bother asking why this is happening, becuase this is just life with open source. Stuff just changes and breaks randomly and without warning all the time.

All I would like to know is: how do I get Compiz effects working again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried `unity --reset` in a terminal?

Comment: Surprisingly, that worked, even though I use gnome-classic and not unity. Thanks for that. After I ran the command, the Unity interface came up, but I logged out, and logged in again, and gnome-classic with effects was working again.